# How to get the array order number by content?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, discord.js

I want to get the array order number by content, my array looks like that:

```
[ 
  [ '560134275538747403', 39953 ], <- 0
  [ '411510958020624384', 36164 ]  <- 1
]           (ID)         (VALUE)
```

To get the array I should use the ID (I have it already), then the output that I need is the number.
For example, `'560134275538747403'` will give you `0`, and `'411510958020624384'` will give you `1`, and...
How to do that? ~and thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with a callback.

```js
function findIndex(array, value) {
    return array.findIndex(([v]) => v === value);
}

var array = [['560134275538747403', 39953], ['411510958020624384', 36164]];

console.log(findIndex(array, '560134275538747403')); // 0
console.log(findIndex(array, '411510958020624384')); // 1
```

Comment: This one is short and simple

Answer (score 0):

You could create a map using `Array.prototype.reduce` - use your string value as the key and it's index number as the value. Something like this:

```js
function generateIndexMap(arr) {
  return Object.values(arr.map(a => a[0])).reduce((accum, el, idx) => {
    accum[el] = idx;
    return accum;
  }, {});
}

const arr = [ ['560134275538747403', 39953], ['411510958020624384', 36164] ];
const indexMap = generateIndexMap(arr);

console.log(indexMap['560134275538747403']);
console.log(indexMap['411510958020624384']);
```

Comment: It's really not complex - if it's confusing to anyone, spending 5 mins reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values and this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce should clear any confusion up.